# How can I select a specific occurrence on the entire page using CSS?

Tags: css

I have tried :nth-of-type and :nth-child, but those don't work for selecting a specific instance on the entire page. For example, if I wanted to select the 8th `div.box` element below ("plane") how can I do this?

```
<div>
 <div class="box">blueberry</div>
 <div class="box">cherry</div>
 <div class="box">pineapple</div>
 <div class="box">orange</div>
 <div class="box">grape</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="box">car</div>
 <div class="box">boat</div>
 <div class="box">plane</div>
 <div class="box">bike</div>
 <div class="box">motorcycle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easy solution would be to add another identifier like an ID or class, is that not an option?

Comment: Your offset (in this case below "plane"), is dynamic? From which point onwards do you want to have this selector?

Comment: `body > div:nth-child(2) > div.box:nth-child(3)`? Assuming the parent of the outer divs is body...

Comment: I don't have control of the HTML. The elements div.box are scattered throughout the page. Is there no way to just select the 8th occurrence overall without having to figure out the parent? I tried using the parents but in my specific situation it's too complicated (I am trying to build a solution for non-technical people).

Comment: `div+div>div:nth-child(3)` would do it but it really depends on the actual HTML

Comment: It's the third `div.box` under the second `div`. The DOM and CSSOM counts things in tree form, not by other axes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. I don't think you can do such a specific task with CSS, but I'm not sure.

```js
let base = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

let divs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
  let elems = base[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (let j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
    divs.push(elems[j])
  }
}
  
function findNElement(n) {
  return divs[n-1].textContent; // This is to return text. Remove .textContent to remove th element
}


console.log(findNElement(8));
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="box">blueberry</div>
 <div class="box">cherry</div>
 <div class="box">pineapple</div>
 <div class="box">orange</div>
 <div class="box">grape</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="box">car</div>
 <div class="box">boat</div>
 <div class="box">plane</div>
 <div class="box">bike</div>
 <div class="box">motorcycle</div>
</div>
```

You can use this snippet to select a certain element of the textContent of the element.

Answer (score 0):

For the completely general case, where you do not know the document's structure (i.e. div.box elements are 'scattered' as you say) I think you'll need Javascript.

The element you want is

```
  document.querySelectorAll('div.box')[7]
```

of course you'll want to check that it actually exists before trying to do anything with  it so something like:

```js
    function findBox(n) { //n starts at 1
      const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('div.box');
      if (boxes.length >= n) return boxes[n-1];
      else return false;
    }
    let n = 8;
    let box = findBox(n);
    if (box) {
      box.style.backgroundColor = 'silver';
    }
    else {
      console.log('There is no ' + n + 'div.box');
    }
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="box">blueberry</div>
 <div class="box">cherry</div>
 <div class="box">pineapple</div>
 <div class="box">orange</div>
 <div class="box">grape</div>
</div>
<div>
 <div class="box">car</div>
 <div class="box">boat</div>
 <div class="box">plane</div>
 <div class="box">bike</div>
 <div class="box">motorcycle</div>
</div>
```